# HTML PHP - How to check if the username already existed

Tags: php, html, mysql

The script is already working fine but I want to insert a command that allows only if the username is not yet used.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $firstname = htmlentities($_POST['firstname'], ENT_QUOTES);
    $lastname = htmlentities($_POST['lastname'], ENT_QUOTES);
    $position = htmlentities($_POST['position'], ENT_QUOTES);
    $username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES);
    $password = htmlentities($_POST['password_two'], ENT_QUOTES);
    $uniqid = uniqid('', true);
    if ( $firstname == '' || $lastname == '' ||  $position == '' || $username == '' || $password == '') {
        $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
        renderForm($error, $firstname, $lastname, $position, $username, $password);

    } else {
        if ($stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO employee (uniqid, firstname, lastname, position, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
            $stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $uniqid, $firstname, $lastname, $position, $username, $password);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
        } else {
            echo "ERROR: Could not prepare SQL statement.";
        }
        header("Location: regemployee.php");
    }
} else {
    renderForm();
}
```

Comment: Before inserting it into the database have a check be selecting with the username posted and if the query returns the value 0 you can insert or else through out an error message without inserting.

Comment: `select count(*) from YOUR_TABLE where YOUR_CONDITION`

Comment: In the else part you make it as if else after selecting the data from the table. `if($count==0){// Insert Coding goes here } else {//Error message goes here}`.

Comment: can you insert your code in my existing code pls thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make username unique on the DB, then when you try to insert the same username in to the DB again, the insert will through an error.

Alternatively you could do a `SELECT * FROM employee WHERE username = ?` and check if results is > 0.

Then you would know it exists already.

Comment: the username is unique. can u insert your answer to my code pls thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do another `SELECT` query which checks if the submitted `username` already exist:

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM employee WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
$stmt->execute();
```

Then get the number of results:

```
$stmt->store_result();
$noofres = $stmt->num_rows;
$stmt->close();
```

Then, create a condition that if it yet doesn't exist, it will do the insert query:

```
if($noofres == 0){

    /* INSERT QUERY HERE */

} else {

    echo 'Username already taken.';

}
```

Comment: where will i insert the new sql query?

Comment: how about a code on where to insert you snippets, im new to web pls. thanks

Comment: hello sir are you there?

Comment: @Maki - You just have to put your insert query inside the `if()` condition